# Meteor server response slow when importing collection

Tags: meteor

I have a MongoDB collection `Foods` in my Meteor app with about 8000 entries with almost 1000 fields each.

For some reason, since I included it, the response time when I call a server method from the client is very slow (seconds). For debugging, I've been removing things one by one. Now, I don't use the collection in any of the functions involved (I've even replaced the server method with just a console.log), and yet if I add the line `import { Foods } from '../imports/collections.js';` to the server, the response is slow, and if I don't it is fast.

Does anyone have any idea why this could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** OP has already answered his question satisfactory. However, the following information should be pointed out, especially for those who face similar issues in context of controlling Meteor's autopublish behavior.

---

As long as autopublish exists in your packages list, each collection publishes to the client at the very moment, your `Mongo.Collection` is created.

See this code of the [Mongo.Collection constructor](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/mongo/collection.js#L27).

Autopublish is then triggered, even just by importing your file that contains a Mongo.Collection constructor to be called (which is very likely your case).

However, you dont need to remove the `autopublish` package if you only want this one collection to prevent auto publishing.

Your Mongo.Collection constructor accepts as second parameter an object with options. To prevent auto publish only for this collection (while having `autopublish` active) you can add the following option:

```js
{
    _preventAutopublish: true,
    // ... other options if desired
}
```

An example for your given Foods collection could be

```js
export const Foods = new Mongo.Collection('foods', {_preventAutopublish: true});
```

Although the option [is not documented](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection), it works and comes in very handy when prototyping.

However, keep in mind that `autopublish` is [not secure](https://guide.meteor.com/security.html#checklist) and should never be present in a release that is expected to be deployed on a server.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was easy.

As said in the [Meteor docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html),

> By default, Meteor automatically publishes every document in your collection to each connected client. To turn this behavior off, remove the autopublish package

So, simply by importing the collection, Meteor interprets that you want to publish it all, and that is what was making it slow, even if I wasn't explicitly using it.

Comment: Why would you answer your own question with basically the same answer that someone else provided? Reward the man for their efforts with some fake internet points

Comment: Simply because, when I answered, he hadn't answered yet.., and answering your own question is acceptable in SO. And I did upvote his answer, when he posted it.

Comment: Hey, sorry to not mention it. I basically wanted to answer with that extended information because I thought it was helpful to you and others since I struggled with a similar issue very long time last month. I will add it to my answer as an edit.

Comment: Yeah I actually read your answer as a reply/extension of mine, with further helpful info:)